# Как подписывать API запросы между Android и Бекенд сервером?

Tags: android, ios, api, безопасность, backend

У нас в компании на стороне Android и iOS приложения используется авторизация через СМС.

Но в последнее время участились случаи атак по типу смс-бомбера
С куча IP адресов шлют разные телефоны на регистрацию/авторизацию
Смс дело не дешевое, около 2 рублей за 1 штуку.
Секретности в передаче данных нету, суть в том чтобы отправлялись запросы только с реальных устройств. Понятно что, от опытного хакера не защититься, но хотя бы от мамкиных хакеров

Есть вариант подписания запросов:

- Приложение шлет запрос авторизации на сервер с номером телефона
- Сервер приложения формирует подпись исходя из номера телефона, текущего времени и какого нибудь хеша
- Отправляет приложению API-KEY
- Приложение генерирует подпись из телефона и API-KEY и отправляет обратно на сервер - телефон, API-KEY и свою подпись
- Сервер проверяет и отправляет смс

Может кто может предложить свой вариант ?

Comment: у гугловской Firebase авторизация в смс бесплатная, до 10000 штук в месяц. И там юзер должен быть с учеткой гугл аккаунта, ботов не напасёшься

Comment: беда только что у нас в месяц порядка 150 000 сообщений и у 80% нет учетки гугл

Comment: Я в вашем варианте вообще не увидел никакой защиты от спама) Просто лишнее действие перед отправкой. Реально поможет, скорее всего, только капча, или авторизация через соц. сети

Comment: еще встречал такой вариант: на номер запросившего авторизацию совершается дозвон и потом просят ввести четыре последние цифры звонившего номера. Это вообще бесплатно получается.Хотя ваш вопрос это не решит. Вам только черный список частично может помочь.